# Using a Python 2.7 enum from C

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I have an enum in Python (backported `enum` package to 2.7) that is meant to be of only integers:

```python
import enum
class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
  val = 0
```

Let's say I receive a `PyObject *` in a C extension pointing to `MyEnum.val`. I want the integer value associated with the `PyObject *`. How do I get it most succinctly?

Comment: As far as I know, the `enum34` package doesn't provide any special C representation or API, so you just have to call `PyObject_GetAttr` and friends, as with any other pure-Python type.

Comment: Does it provide anything that'd let me unify code-paths for handling them alongside objects `x` for which `PyInt_Check(x) != 0`? e.g. support for built-in protocols, something like `PyNumber_Int(x)` (if that actually worked).

Comment: `Enum` values are explicitly designed _not_ to act like they're a subtype of `int`. `IntEnum` values are another story. You should be able to `PyInt_Check` those and `PyInt_AsLong` them. But for `Enum`, you shouldn't be able to, so you (at least should) need to get the `value` attr if you want to use them as ints, just as you do from Python.

Comment: Using `enum.IntEnum` on the Python-side instead of `enum.Enum` does seem to be the most convenient path to take then. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it's convenient if it's what you actually want. Two different `IntEnum` types' constants will compare equal to each other—e.g., `Colors.red == Days.sunday` will be true. The [`IntEnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intenum) docs explain why usually, that's _not_ what you want… but of course sometimes it is, which is why they included it in the module.

Comment: It is; I failed to elucidate that in the original question formulation. I've edited the question to clarify the intent.

Comment: Even if the values are all integers, that usually doesn't mean you want an `IntEnum`. The docs I linked explain it better than I can.

Comment: The enumeration is meant to mirror integers coming from a spec. The extra fluff of identity carried by `enum.Enum` doesn't seem to be what I want.

Comment: OK, so you're basically using them like C `#define` macros? In that case, yeah, `IntEnum` is effectively that with better debugging output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source to the [`enum34`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) backport, just like the [`enum`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/enum.py) module in 3.4+, it's pure Python, and does nothing to expose a custom C API.

So, you just use [`PyObject_GetAttr`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetAttr) and friends to access class attributes. In particular, if you have a `MyEnum.val`, you need to get its `value` attribute, which will be an `int`, which you can then `PyInt_AsLong`.

This is the same way things work in Python. If you try to use `MyEnum.val` where an `int` is expected, you should get a `TypeError`; if you try to explicitly call `int(MyEnum.val)`, you will *definitely* get a `TypeError`. So, although I haven't tested it, `PyInt_AsLong` directly on the constant instead of its `value` should raise a `TypeError` and return -1.

If you want enumeration constants that act like subtypes of `int`, then, as the [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#module-contents) docs explain, you want [`IntEnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intenum). Usually, that isn't really what you want (as the docs explain), but if it is, of course it works. And you should be able to `PyInt_Check` and `PyInt_AsLong` an `IntEnum` value (although, again, I haven't tested).